# Corrigir tradução de "reviews all-time"

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tradução, localização

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## In English:

**This translation is wrong.**
It translates "reviews all-time" to "best reviews".
This has been ignored or forgotten since January...  please correct this so we feel our time finding bugs/wrong translations is not wasted.

> #### Correct text: "análises no total"

Comment: será que algum moderador não poderia mudar isso já? qualquer sugestão que pegarem aqui é melhor do que está hoje, não faz o menor sentido do jeito que está

Comment: we also need a translation for the case when the number of reviews is 1, like in `1 review all-time`

Comment: @m0sa will the system know when there is only one review? If so, following the @bfavaretto's and Sergio's suggestion it would become: `1 análise no total`, otherwise (the system doesn't know the review number) it would be: `x análise(s) no total`

Comment: @m0sa: thanks for fast reply! The singular for that would be to drop the `s` in the first word. So `análise no total` as @Math also pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated translations will deployed with build rev `2014.4.*.1560`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: @Sergio You should mark this one as accepted, instead of mine.

Comment: @bfavaretto, correct, just did that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Sugestão: **análises no total**

Comment: +1 - funciona bem aos meus ouvidos portuguêses

Comment: prefiro essa sugestão, pois dá pra ler o número e esse texto logo em seguida fazendo uma frase com sentido: `17 análises no total`